# QuantumLeap, OrionCB and IoTagent-LoRaWAN integration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, lorawan

I was reading [the QuantumLeap docs](https://quantumleap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#operation) and I was wondering how those Generic Enablers are integrated, I mean, I've deployed the docker containers and apparently are all running, in fact I've been able to create a device in the IoTagent-LoRaWAN with the POST request which I'm also able to retrieve with the GET request to `http://localhost:4061/iot/devices`; however and it's apparently receiving the info from TTN as the log shows:

```
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-24T19:23:04.759Z","level":"info","message":"New message in topic"}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-24T19:23:04.760Z","level":"info","message":"IOTA provisioned devices:"}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-24T19:23:04.760Z","level":"info","message":"Decoding CaynneLPP message:AQIBbA=="}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-24T19:23:04.760Z","level":"error","message":"Could not cast message to NGSI"}
```

However ... there is a last error message that I don't know if could cause problems, `"level":"error","message":"Could not cast message to NGSI"`

Also ... I don't know how should I proced now with OrionCB and QuantumLeap because ... QuantumLeap docs talk about create an OrionCB subscription, but ... I had understood from OrionCB docs that subscriptions are created to follow a previously created entity, so .. should I create both?

Is QuantumLeap storing info from any created subscription in OrionCB? How can I tight an entity to that IoTagent-LoRaWAN device created?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, It was apparently again a problem with `docker-compose.yml` file; it was not deploying correctly the mongoDB container thus OrionCB cannot connect to it.

When all containers are deployed the IoTagent should be able to create an new entity when you add a new device, then creating the proper subscription in OrionCB pointing the notifications to QuantumLeap should work:

```
    {
        "description": "Test subscription",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
            {
                "idPattern": ".*",
                "type": "Room"
            }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": [
                "temperature"
                ]
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "http": {
                "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
            },
            "attrs": [
            "temperature"
            ],
            "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified"]
        },
        "throttling": 5
    }
```